# Constructor with bool param allows Java-esque code to compile

Tags: c++

This blew my mind today until I realized it only [compiles](http://ideone.com/vLVBK4) with boolean params.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
    bool _param;
public:
    Foo(bool param) {
        _param = param;
    }
    void say() {
        cout << "Param is "<< _param << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(true);
    foo.say();
    return 0;
}
```

I also noticed that the constructor is invoked *twice*, then my guess is that the pointer created by "new Foo(true)" is being casted to a boolean. Is that it? If so, why it does not work with other parameter types? Is there anything else that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Marking the constructor `explicit` might allow you to find error quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo foo = new Foo(true);
```

is equivalent to

```
   Foo foo(new Foo(true));
```

and the pointer result of `new` turns into `true`.

That's why it compiles, and you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41330465/817643)'s answer. The reason it (seemingly) only works with `bool`, is that pointers could be used since the dawn of [c](/questions/tagged/c) as boolean operands. So the implicit conversion must exist.

Comment: That's the piece I was missing. Thanks.